# How to detect tap on Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, tap

I want to detect the tap on the phone (Windows 7 OS), but not on the touch screen (probably on the side of the device). I am not sure whether it could be implemented with the accelerometer data. any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the app, but probably we can consider Tap as Shake. If so take a look on

[Shake that Windows Phone 7 and detect it](http://mark.mymonster.nl/2010/10/24/shake-that-windows-phone-7-and-detect-it/)

[Windows Phone Shake Gestures Library](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/02/22/windows-phone-shake-gestures-library.aspx)

or similar. There is a *ShakeGestureEventArgs* arg that holds a ShakeType property that identifies the direction of the shake gesture.